# Error: Unknown property 'grid template columns'

Tags: css, csslint

How to fix this error?

```
Unknown property grid-template-columns.
Expected RBRACE at line 900 (there are no missing RBRACE's)
```

Comment: You are sure there's a semicolon after the previous line?

Comment: Can you show us the CSS please?